# UITextView : Make a UIButton inline with UITextView text iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in which there is `UIButton` at the bottom right corner. My `UITextView` allows multiline text, i.e The textView height dynamically increases on typing enter key (similar to SMS app). But my problem is that on typing text, the text goes behind the `UIButton`. I want the text to stop when it reaches image and continue in next line without any break in text. Is this possible?[image]

Comment: Hi @JMS, did you found an appropriate solution?

Comment: I used exclusion path to implement it. But everytime text changes in `UITextView`, we need to reset the exclusion path (try in `scrollViewDidScroll` method)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to subclass UITextView to modify exclusion path right in-place.

Comment: @JMS i am facing same issue. Can u provide code in answers for fixing this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

this solution work for me. I have subclass of UItextview where i put this code.

```
UIBezierPath* exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_buttonClear.frame];
        self.textContainer.exclusionPaths  = @[exclusionPath];
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the same as above. But the problem is that my `UITextView` height keeps increasing and this causes y value to change. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Text Kit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html) provided by apple. you can achieve this

Here is the ray wenderlich tut
https://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial

Specifically the part you have to do is set `exclusionPaths` for your UITextView

```
UIBezierPath* exclusionPath = [_timeView curvePathWithOrigin:myButton.center];
_textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths  = @[exclusionPath];
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
UIBezierPath* exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:Button.frame];
        self.textContainer.exclusionPaths  = @[exclusionPath];
```

Use UITextView Delegate and do something like,

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{

    //Get Buttons Y position and Allow TextView Frame changes until it is less than or equal buttons Y position

    if (textView.frame.origin.y+textView.frame.size.height < Button.frame.origin.y) {

        CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
        CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
        CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
        textView.frame = newFrame;
    }

}
```